# Having some problems on this SQL homework assignment

Tags: sql

I've been stuck on this question in particular for some time now and haven't got a clue what to do. The question says this: Create a list of players, their fees and their physical. Sort your list so that the higher value fees are at the top, followed by those that have had a physical.  Using column aliases, duplicate your output to look like the following:

```
Person ID                                     Fee Player Physical
----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------
        119                                   25.00 Y
        120                                   25.00 Y
        121                                   25.00 Y
        123                                   25.00 Y
        125                                   25.00 Y
        127                                   25.00 Y
        129                                   25.00 Y
        130                                   25.00 Y
        131                                   25.00 Y
        132                                   25.00 Y
        136                                   25.00 Y
        138                                   25.00 Y
        141                                   25.00 Y
        142                                   25.00 Y
        143                                   25.00 Y
        137                                   25.00 N
        135                                   25.00 N
        140                                   25.00 N
        133                                   25.00 N
        126                                   25.00 N
        124                                   25.00 N
        118                                   25.00 N
        117                                    0.00 Y
        128                                    0.00 Y
        134                                    0.00 Y
        122                                    0.00 N
        139                                    0.00 N
        145                                    0.00 N
```

This is what it is supposed to look like once you are done with it.

```
select Person ID, Fee, Player Physical
from playerrec;
order by Fee desc, Player Physical;
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. Is what I got in the end. I'm a bit confused since playerrec is my alias for this query.

Comment: You are NOT using all 3 tagged database engines. Tag only the one that you are ACTUALLY using.

Comment: I have removed the tags for multiple databases which is clearly not the case. As mentioned in comments tag the relevant database accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Object names cannot contain spaces unless the object is encompassed by brackets.  Also, it needs a `FROM` clause.  Also, it's not necessary to repeat ORDER BY 3 times, only once.  Please try it this way

```
select [Person ID]
     , [Fee]
     , [Player Physical]
from playerrec
order by [Fee] desc, [Player Physical] desc, [Person ID] asc;
```

Comment: Really? 3 order by clauses?

Comment: ORDER BY [Fee] desc, [Player Physical] desc, [Person ID] ASC;

Comment: I tried it out but I got an error message. Invalid object name 'YourTable'.

Comment: Updated please try again